# Algorithm for deleting/inserting/retriving elements in a linked list with O(sqrt(n)) complexity

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

our assignment is to implement a linked list class to do the following with time complexity of O(sqrt(n)):

1. insert an element at i th place
2. delete an element at i th place
3. retrive i th element of the list.

I found a few data structures like skip list. but the time complexity should be O(sqrt(n)).

anyone can help?

Comment: Can it be less than sqrt or does it have to be **exactly** sqrt(n)

Comment: @Daniel That's not how Big O notation works.

Comment: I think it should be exactly sqrt(n) however "any function that is O(log n) is also O(sqrt(N))"
It would be OK if there is a special algorithm with O(sqrt(n)), else I may use skip list or something.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't  Big Theta you need to be using ? (Looks like` Θ(n)` ). If it's big O then using something that runs **faster** than what was asked shouldn't loose you any points. And if it does, you go point out to the instructor how Big O works and what Big Θ is and make them feel ashamed to be a Computer Science instructor (and get your points back).

Comment: Remember that `O(sqrt(n))` means that the algorithm needs to run **at least as fast (or faster)** than `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: Skip Lists as described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list do *not* satisfy the given problem.  They have `O(log(N))` expected time, not `O(log(N))` worst case time.  Wikipedia notes that a deterministic version can also be made to provide `O(log(N))` searches, but only by running an `O(N)` structure rearrangement process.

Comment: Yeah, if you want it to be "exactly sqrt(n)" and have a faster algorithm, just insert a loop after it: `for 1..sqrt(n) do something useless`.  There ya go!

Comment: @rlb.usa: I thought so, but I wasn't sure. We never did focus much on Big O notation in my classes (damn shame too). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you having a little trouble understanding the Big O notation?

Remember, Big O means "Upper Bound".

Mathematically, `f(x) = O( g(x) )` **if** `f(x) <= C ( g(x) )`.

That means, we can say that `f(x) is O(x^2)` and `f(x) is O(x^1000000000)`, because `O(x^2)` and `O(x^1000000000)` are both upper bounds (though, not necessarily "good" upper bounds).

Now, Skip Lists are O(log n) time, as you researched.

That means because `log(n) < sqrt(n)` ,
we can say that Skip Lists are also `O( sqrt(n) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Skip lists have complexity `O(log n)` for search, deletion and insertion, so they satisfy your requirement. Remember that any function that is `O(log n)` is also `O(sqrt(N))`, because `sqrt` grows asymptotically faster than `log`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this should be doable with a simplified version of the skip list idea using only two linked lists.  But you would need to be somewhat clever with the algorithms to make sure that the maximum number of elements in the shorter list is bounded by `O(sqrt(N))` and the maximum distance in the longer list between adjacent elements of the shorter list is also bounded by `O(sqrt(N))`.